# What synchronization primitive do I need?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization

Here is a hypothetical scenario (this is not homework):

Several people are in a kitchen with a table and a sink. They can all be eating at the same time. However, only one can be using the sink at a time, and whenever someone is using the sink, no one can be eating.

What synchronization primitive would be required and how would it need to be set up? If this required a semaphore (say, a .NET one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx ), how would one configure and use it to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typical reader-writer problem. Readers can read at the same time (assuming no writer is writing), and only one writer can write at anytime, and no body reads when someone is writing.

[Reader-writer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem).

Comment: +1 @zzk - you beat me to it! See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As zzk says, this is a multiple reader/single writer scenario, and on .NET you would typically use a [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) type of lock for synchronizing access to the resource